# Will jQuery escape my quotes properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I'm using $.cookie() to pull all the values from a cookie, in JSON format:

`var props = $.cookie('params');`

`props` returns:

`{"distinct_id": "13f97d6600b42e-000e6293c-6b1b2e75-232800-13f97d6600cc82","utm_source": "the_source","utm_term": "myterms","utm_campaign": "campaign","utm_medium": "medium","utm_content": "content"}`

I'm inserting this dynamically into a form with jQuery, and I want to ensure everything is going to `POST` properly, even though there's all kinds of crazy characters that could be in there which would normally conflict with HTML (fully qualified urls, `&`, `"`, `'`, maybe even a `>` or `<`)

I also need to make certain it works in IE6, IE7, etc.

```
var input = $('<input type="hidden" name="CustomField1">');
input.appendTo($('form[data-params=track]')).val(props);
```

It would *appear* to be working, but I want to make 100% sure I'm doing this right as it's quite important there are no bugs for this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure `val()` does not need any additional escaping as you are not actually editing raw HTML. `val()` sets DOM `value` on an element.

Generally setting attributes or properties through DOM/jQuery should be fine. Those will be auto-escaped when rendering `innerHtml`. But if you submit a page it does not even have to render anything -- it can just directly copy values from DOM to request.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are setting the value of an input field, it should just work fine, there is no need to escape/process any characters in the input's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript `escape()` function to make sure the string get's escaped properly for display in the browser.

Comment: It's a hidden input, and I'm not displaying it, just sending it through a POST request